# How to detect on ios7 all available bluetooth devices?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, bluetooth

I would like to find all available bluetooth devices (device name, and RSSI) on ios7, but i dont know how. I tried to use Core Bluetooth framework, but it doesnt see my android phone, and my windows notebook...
But if i go to the settings -> Bluetooth it show my phone and other devices.

Which framework should i have to use for this?

(I use an ipad 3 to test my application.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [LGBluetooth](https://github.com/DavidSahakyan/LGBluetooth), here is a basic code for scanning peripherals.

```
[[LGCentralManager sharedInstance] scanForPeripheralsByInterval:4
                                                     completion:^(NSArray *peripherals)
 {
      for (LGPeripheral *peripheral in peripherals) {
          NSLog(@"Name: %@ RSSI: %d", peripheral.name, peripheral.RSSI);
      }
 }];
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesnt show the bluetooth devices... i tried the LGBluetooth example app, but not show the nearby devices.